# cURL is not working properly except when i put exit()

Tags: php, curl

cURL will work fine if I put `exit()` after this code:

```
$url = "http://wpmsqa01.xyz.net/stwpmsp/update.php?cmd=changeplan&siteid=876&splan=174";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$response=curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
$get_resp=htmlentities($response);
```

But, if I remove `exit()`, it Won't work.

Comment: define "won't work". what'S happening (or not hapepning)?

Comment: It will return true, but not happening(Result is not updated).

Comment: You're not doing anything with the contets you get - so what's supposed to happen? YOu have set RETURNTRANSFER, so curl won't output the contents, but return them. They're inside $response, and you even work with them, storing a escaped version in $get_resp. But you're never outputting them.